# Does hydroxychloroquine make tardive dyskinesia worse?

Tags: neurology, rheumatology

I found this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5472076/#s6title) which suggests to me that chloroquine (hydroxychloroquine?) can make tardive dyskinesia worse. Is my reading of it accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper you reference postulates that this occurs in patients who have malaria

> Another hypothesis is that the fever associated with malaria may directly decrease brain amines (norepinephrine, dopamine, and serotonin) because of the malaria-induced spike in temperature. Spikes in temperature can disrupt brain amine function (including synthesis and signaling activity) that can be further exacerbated by exposure to the antimalarials.82

Comment: So not in people who don't have malaria?

Comment: Well, they're saying it's fever that is the issue when taking anti-malarials.

Comment: I know this is not a site for medical advice, but I usually take hydroxychloroquine and of course I'm unable to obtain it now, so I've been off it for a few days and I feel like my TD improved. And this is right around the time my botox should be wearing off, which I also can't get because doctors aren't seeing patients.

Comment: You are right, it's not for personal medical advice.

Comment: Hydroxychloroquine has a half life of 22 days.